# Can't get read.table to work with stdin without closing buffer

Tags: r, stream, stdout, stdin, read.table

After Googling for a few days and not finding an answer I thought I'd post it here:

I've got a tricky R problem I can't seem to solve when reading from stdin using read.table.  Unfortunately, due to the model/process that I'm using, readLines and strsplit are too inefficient - so I'd like to stick with read.table if possible as it gives me like 100 times speedup.

Anyways, here's what my situation looks like:

```
inStream = file("stdin","r")

while(TRUE){
  data_chunk = tryCatch(read.table(file=inStream,header=FALSE,sep="\t"), error=function(e) NULL)

  if(is.null(data_chunk)) break

  <Do some R modeling with the chunk of data...>
}
```

I'm using the tryCatch to check for an error when it hits the end of the stream and stop the loop.

According to the documentation of read.table, if you supply a new line or EOF to the stdin stream, it should signal to read.table to stop, and move on - however if I try a continuous stream (even with new lines or EOFs in the stream) it just hangs waiting for the stdout buffer to close.

Is there a way to do this with read.table - or even a more efficient way to use readLines or something?  I need to be able to process the stdin stream in big chunks without a huge performance hit.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!